# Intersection of two planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I have two planes which i have to intercept, but my answer isn't correct (i think)

Plane I $= (-14, 8, 3, 3) + r(3,3−,3,0) + s(1, −1, −3, −1)$

Plane II $= (-7, 1, 3, 6) + u(-2, 0, -2, -2) + v(-3, 1, -2, 3)$

then i mount this matrix and use Gauss-Jordan method
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   -3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & |&7 \\
   3 & -1 & 0 & -1 & |&-7 \\
   -3 & -3 & 2 & 2 & |&0 \\
   0 & -1 & 2 & -3 &|& 3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

It returned $x_1 =2$, but haven't this option to chose. Im wrong or this question no make sense? im so confused lol.

Comment: What do you mean by *It returned $x_1 =2$, but haven't this option to chose*?

Comment: Its a multiple choice question

Answer (score 1):

I think the matrix is incorrect, please refer below

$$-14 + 3r + s = -7 -2u -3v \implies 3r + s + 2u +3v = 7$$

$$8 -3r -s = 1 +0u +v \implies -3r -s +0u -v = -7$$

$$3 + 3r -3s = 3 - 2u-2v \implies 3r -3s + 2u + 2v = 0$$

$$3 + 0r - s = 6 -2u +3v \implies 0r-s+2u-3v = -3$$

Hence the matrix looks like

$$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ -3 & -1 & 0 &-1 \\ 3 & -3 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & -1 &2 &-3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}r \\ s \\ u \\ v\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}7 \\ -7 \\ 0 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Now when you solve this matrix, you will get values of $r,s,u,v$ for which the planes intersect. The next step would be to input either in one plane or the other the corresponding variable values to get the line of intersection

Comment: Thats return 2. I have to choice the options: -8, -3. -9, -6, -10, -7, -4, and -5.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about how the method works. You assume there exists a point $P$, which lie both in plane I and plane II:
$$
\vec P = \vec a_1+\vec b_1 r+\vec c_1 s=\vec a_2+\vec b_2 u+\vec c_2 v,
$$

thus you make it an equation:
$$
\vec b_1 r+\vec c_1 s-\vec b_2 u-\vec c_2 v = \vec a_2-\vec a_1
$$

which can be written is matrix form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11}&c_{11}&b_{21}&c_{21} \\
b_{12}&c_{12}&b_{22}&c_{22} \\
b_{13}&c_{13}&b_{23}&c_{23} \\
b_{14}&c_{14}&b_{24}&c_{24} \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
r\\s\\-u\\-v
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{21}-a_{11}\\a_{22}-a_{12}\\a_{23}-a_{13}\\a_{24}-a_{14}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
To solve this, you use the Gauss method or any other.

But note that, you are solving for $r,s,u,v$, not the coordinate of the point $P$.

Comment: How i can find the point P? and in this case, the point P is the point of intercept ?

Comment: If you have found r and s, you can put them into the plane equation

Comment: Sure!! Finally i find the answer. Thanks a lot